# jQuery: why doesn't radio button's change event handler retrigger?

Tags: jquery, events, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons...

```
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="foo">
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="bar">
```

that when checked will use a confirm() to ask if the user really wants to check that radio button or cancel. If user cancels I want the radio button to be unchecked so that user can repeat the same process if necessary:

```
    $("input [type=radio]").change(function() {
        if(confirm_canceled) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false).trigger('change');
        }
    });
```

The radio button is unchecked but if I click the radio button again the event handler isn't activated. I guess it's because change() triggers on changes on the value and nothing has changed, so how do I fix this?

edit: issue was a bug caused by using confirm instead of confirm_canceled * face palm *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
 var checked = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (!checked) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="foo">
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="bar">
```

Comment: Weird. Your code works but mine, which is almost identical, doesn't. How the heck do I debug this...?!

Comment: It's probably the space after input before the square bracket, `input [...`

Comment: omg i can't believe the error was in using confirm as variable name if the if statement. wtf has i thinking. Your solution made me look at the code more closely.